# How to access the console (browser) log from Selenium::Remote::Driver

Tags: selenium, perl, console.log

I am trying to access the console log from the perl module `Selenium::Remote::Driver` to no avail.

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver), this should be very simple, by calling the `get_log` method with the log type as a parameter, which as I figure should be `browser`. However, the `get_log_types` method  returns only the `server` log type as available, while the documentation says "every driver should have client,driver, **browser**, and server types".

I believe some parameters should be passed to the constructor (in `chromeOptions` maybe?) that switches on capturing the console log. Unfortunately, all examples I find for this are for other languages, and this perl module is too much different to port those solutions.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$web_driver->get_log('browser')` works for me with Selenium::Chrome, no special options. I use the following to check for JS errors: `# Warning: This clears the log.
sub has_js_failed {
   my $log = $web_driver->get_log('browser');
   return 0+grep { no warnings qw( uninitialized ); $_->{level} eq 'SEVERE' && $_->{source} eq 'javascript' } @$log;
}`

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I cannot use Selenium::Chrome, I have a Zalenium server (basically a Selenium HUB) at the remote end.